# Remove unsupported tags of html (Simple HTML Dom)

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I would like to remove unsupported tags of html inserted by users (system define which tag is supported), example system is only supported "**div**" tag:

```
<div><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span></div>
```

will convert to:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

This is my code with Simple HTML DOM:

```
function main()
{
    $content = '<div><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span></div>';

    $html = str_get_html($content);

    $html = htmlParser($html);
}

function htmlParser($html)
{
    $supportedTags = ['div'];

    foreach ($html->childNodes() as $node) {
        // Remove unsupported tags
        if (!in_array($node->tag, $supportedTags)) {
            $node->parent()->innertext = str_replace($node->outertext, $node->innertext, $node->parent()->innertext);
            $node->outertext = '';
        }

        if ($node->childNodes()) {
            htmlParser($node);
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

But thing get wrong if contain multiple nested unsupported tags, eg:

```
<div><span>Hello</span> <span>World</span> <span><b>!!</b></span></div>
```

it will be converted to

```
<div>Hello World <b>!!</b></div>
```

but expected result is

```
<div>Hello World !!</div>
```

What is the solution? Should I continue to use Simple HTML DOM or find another way to solve this issue?

Thanks for solving my problem in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some struggles, I found out I should not edit $node->parent() as it's in a loop and should load the childNodes first. The code should be like this:

```
function htmlParser($html)
{
    $supportedTags = ['div'];

    foreach ($html->childNodes() as $node) {
        if ($node->childNodes()) {
            htmlParser($node);
        }

        // Remove unsupported tags
        if (!in_array($node->tag, $supportedTags)) {
            $node->outertext = $node->innertext;
        }
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with as much as I understand. `strip_tags($html, '<div><b>');`

**Example** : https://3v4l.org/p4nLV

---

**Reference** : http://php.net/strip_tags

Comment: The reason I don't want to use strip_tags is because I want to do advance filtering, eg: filter unsupported attibute like <div data-width="50">Hello</div> to <div>Hello</div>